# Flutter 3.0.0 bugs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-upgrade

after upgrading to the latest version 3.0.0 then some various bugs appear in some of my projects that run well before

1. qr_code_scanner:compileRelaseKotlin
   [image]
2. Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree
   [image]
3. Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
   [image]

i have tried some ways

1. Flutter clean then pub get again
2. delete pubspec.lock
3. clean the .pub-cache
4. upgrade gradle to 7.4
5. upgrade ext.kotlin_version to '1.6.10'
6. change android -> build.gradle -> buildscript & allprojects jcenter() to mavenCentral()
7. upgrade Android Gradle Build version to the latest "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'"

for information flutter doctor
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to delete pubspec.lock
run `flutter clean`

run `flutter pub get`

extra step, might help you:
`flutter pub upgrade`

Upgraded dart version to 2.17 in pubspec also.

Fixed on the warning in cached network image, by removing the `?` checks in the warning. The package will be updated by the maintainers, there already is 5 pull requests for the fix, can check [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/pulls).

for iOS, had to delete podfile.lock also and run `pod install --repo-update`

Fixed things and compiled without warnings for iOS and Android.